# error : auth token is expired in firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, token

I'm making a react native application using Firebase realtime database. I wanted to update my database so i imported a new jSON file and i got "data has beed successfully imported "  but then i get no data and i only get an error under my  database name : "error : auth token is expired " like the image below : [image]

1- I checked out and re-logged in again but same problem
2- I created a new project with the same username but still same problem 
3- i created a new project and imported the same file with another username but same problem

PS: i'm sure that my jSON file is valid because i get "data has been imported "
So, any idea please ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem and found your question. Since there wasn't any answers, I went to check the JSON file I have exported from firebase and it actually has the following content:

```
{ 
"error" : "Auth token is expired" 
}
```

So I believe that when we exported the JSON file, the token has already expired.